# react-scripts is not recognized as an internal or external command which have some basic folder structure

Tags: reactjs, npm, package.json

I have a basic folder structure in React by my friend. At first, I run the npm install.
Then, I run the following command to start the server. But could not work out.

Could you please help me and thanks in advance?

Below is my package.json file

```
{
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    
    "todomvc-app-css": "^2.0.0",
    "todomvc-common": "^1.0.0"
  },

  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

*Below is my folder structure *

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbZ9C.png)

Now I am trying to run the npm run start. But it couldn't work. It says that

Comment: can some one please help me?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I udated now. Can you please help me?

Comment: Can some one please help me?